# macro for making a template

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs and trying to figure out if there is an "easy" way to write a macro that will create a template for a standard function specification (see lines with # below).  For example, I would like to execute a command to extract the input and output variables and place them in this standard format above the function (using the R language):

```
#This function does something
#Input:
# var1 - h
# var2 - 
# var3 -
# var4 - 
# Output:
# myoutput -
MyFunction <- function(var1,var2,var3=13,var4=NULL){
...
... 
return(myoutput)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know R so I'm just guessing how it looks from your one example.  Add this to your Emacs init file (and evaluate it or restart), go to a function definition line and <kbd>M-x my-r-insert-function-template</kbd>:

```
(defun my-r-insert-function-template ()
  "Insert a function template."
  (interactive)
  (let (name inputs output pos)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (save-excursion
      (when (re-search-forward "\\([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+\\)\\s-*<-\\s-*function\\s-*(" nil t)
        (setq name (match-string-no-properties 1))
        (backward-char)
        (forward-sexp)
        (setq pos (1- (point)))
        (backward-sexp)
        (while (re-search-forward "[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+" pos 'go)
          (push (match-string-no-properties 0) inputs)
          (search-forward "," pos 'go))
        (search-forward "{")
        (setq pos (point))
        (backward-char)
        (forward-sexp)
        (when (re-search-backward "return\\s-*(\\s-*\\([a-zA-Z0-9\\.]+\\)" pos t)
          (setq output (match-string-no-properties 1)))))
    (when name
      (insert "# " name " : This function does something\n")
      (when inputs
        (insert "# Input:\n")
        (setq inputs (nreverse inputs))
        (dolist (input inputs)
          (insert "# " input " -\n")))
      (when output
        (insert "# Output:\n")
        (insert "# " output " -\n")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use R but it looks like [ESSr-autoyas](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSr-autoyas) could be used to do what you want. It makes use of [YASnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) (a template package for Emacs).